# Swift 3 - performSegue when animation sequence stop

Tags: ios, animation, swift3

I need help because i can't find example to do exactly what I want need anywhere.

I want to animate a simple png sequence, then call a performSegue once it's completed (that's my main problem)

So I tried with

```
InitImage.animationImages = [
    UIImage(named:"load1.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"load2.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"load3.png")!,
 /* 20 more images... */
]

InitImage.animationDuration = 2.5
InitImage.animationRepeattCount = 1
InitImate.startAnimating()
```

so it animates but call the segue too soon.  I found that i should probably use

```
UIView.animate(withDuration : ...)
```

But I can't find an example written in Swift3 that animates a sequence of files.

Could someone show me the way?
thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a UIView animateWithDuration variant that lets you cycle through a series of still images like an animated GIF. You have to use the code you're currently using. Axel's solution of creating a timer that who's duration is calculated so it fires when your animation completes is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I think is to make a timer

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: InitImage.animationDuration * Double(InitImage.animationImages?.count ?? 0), target: self, selector: #selector(push), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

and selector

```
func push() {
.... perform segue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use performSelector with afterDelay, since the self is an @objc UIViewController:

```
self.perform(#selector(segueToDetailViewController), with: self, afterDelay: InitImage.animationDuration)
```

And selector:

```
func segueToDetailViewController() {
    self.performSegue( ... etc ... )
}
```

The code above is not multiplying the animation duration by the number of images because when I ran the code, I found that the animation duration for all images was 2.5 seconds.